# Plotting inequalities

Tags: pdftex, plot, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to plot $x<y$ and $2x<y$, but it doesn't work.

What I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Draw axes
\draw[->] (-4.1,0) -- (4.1,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4.1) -- (0,4.1) node[above] {$y$};

% Draw the region for x < y
\fill[blue!20,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4) -- (-2,2) -- (4,4) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,thick] (-4,-4) -- (4,4) node[below right]{$x<y$};


\fill[red!20,opacity=0.5] (-2,-4) -- (-4,4) -- (2,4) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick] (-2,-4) -- (2,4) node[below right] {$2x<y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I would like to colour whole region something like here
[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the limits of the equality, you just need to add the other corners of the grid (and remove a couple of mistakes).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Draw axes
\draw[->] (-4.1,0) -- (4.1,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4.1) -- (0,4.1) node[above] {$y$};

% Draw the region for x < y
\fill[blue!20,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4) -- (4,4)  -- (-4,4) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,thick] (-4,-4) -- (4,4) node[below right]{$x<y$};


\fill[red!20,opacity=0.5] (-2,-4) -- (2,4) -- (-4,4) -- (-4,-4) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick] (-2,-4) -- (2,4) node[below right] {$2x<y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```